# Firebase simple login using appMobi pop-up windows

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, firebase, appmobi

I am trying to use OAuth simple login from Firebase on mobile devices using Intel appMobi.

```
<button onclick="authClient.login('twitter');">
<button onclick="authClient.login('facebook');">
<button onclick="authClient.login('github');">
<button onclick="authClient.login('persona');">
```

When working on a web site the Firebase simple login works fine for Facebook, Twitter and etc. The user gets a pop-up window to allow login.

When using the appMobi emulator the pop-up window will show up outside the device being emulated and nothing shows up when when the software is loaded onto a mobile device.

Is there a way to get this to work on mobile devices using Javascript?

Comment: It is still not working with Firebase but I did find a document that shows how to get this to work with appMobi and the Intel Cloud Services Login.    http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-the-intel-cloud-services-platform-identity-service-in-the-intel-xdk

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Simple Login currently requires fully-fledged pop-ups to be enabled in the browser environment, which is why you're not able to use it in appMobi. While I'm not fully familiar with appMobi, I suspect that it does not allow opening arbitrary windows via `window.open` and then permitting cross-frame communication via postmessage to the opener.

Redirect-based flows are on the roadmap for Firebase Simple Login which would be a suitable workaround provided there were a way to redirect the user from a foreign page back to your application, but I don't have a timeline on that feature. As an alternative, check out the third-party service [Singly](http://singly.com/), which offers a native [integration with Firebase](https://singly.com/docs/firebase).